# need soql query to pick case documents

Tags: soql

I am using one query SELECT LinkedEntityId,LinkedEntity.Name,

ContentDocument.Id,

ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData

FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN(SELECT Case_GCC__c FROM Subject_GCC__c)
In the above query I have two documents for a case and for first document case is the parent sobject and for second document emailmessage is the parent sobject and both document are stored in contentdocument so in single query how can I pick both documents

SELECT LinkedEntityId,LinkedEntity.Name,

ContentDocument.Id,

ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData

FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN(SELECT Case_GCC__c FROM Subject_GCC__c)